# android menu item description

Tags: android, text, subtext

I know Java, but I am new to Android. I have a question, maybe it is simple but I have searched the web for the past 2 days and I`ve got nothing.
I don't even know how it's called, that's why I have a link to an image [photo](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2552/3924903867_7bb733d5f5.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.flickr.com/photos/andrea-olivato/3925689380/&usg=__mR7LWAf-sn1WMCRMwO79fAt6taA=&h=428&w=320&sz=46&hl=en&start=0&sig2=XdpsJO-YndMjvaSC-hX33Q&zoom=1&tbnid=c_YA0VRICWgvBM%3a&tbnh=138&tbnw=103&ei=GviUTdjQBYTOsga838zGCA&prev=/images?q=android%2blocation&hl=en&biw=1280&bih=800&gbv=2&tbm=isch&itbs=1&iact=hc&vpx=723&vpy=64&dur=123&hovh=260&hovw=194&tx=94&ty=125&oei=GviUTdjQBYTOsga838zGCA&page=1&ndsp=29&ved=1t:429,r:4,s:0) and an example path to it menu->settings->location (for example but in settings almost all items are the same) 
The TextView or the Chechbox items have a text and a description (the text is bigger and the description is smaller in the picture) .The answer is probably pretty simple because almost all items are the same.
and how descriptions change after the new itent has been procesed they have an android:id or something to id them in the code?
thank you for your time!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  It looks like your interested in android Preferences? http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences

Answer (score 0):

you might want to read Custom ListView items and adapters that's what i think is being displayed, Android Series: [Custom ListView items and adapters](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

Answer (score 0):

On the screenshot there is a `ListView`. The item highlighted is a custom ListView item. The highlighted item is not just a single view. It looks like there are 3 views: a vertical `LinearLayout` containing 2 `TextView`, one for title and one for description.